# How to install Debugging Tools with Visual Studio 2017 installer?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, windbg

I need `cdb.exe` as a debugger for QT Creator. I know that cdb is available as a part of Windows SDK, but is not installed when I install Windows SDK through Visual Studio 2017 installer.

On the other hand, if I install Windows SDK standalone (available [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)), I can select "Debugging Tools", and finally I get the expected folder `Debuggers` in `Windows kits`, that contains cdb.

How can I get `cdb` during Visual Studio install?

Comment: VS ships with a compact version of the SDK, only what you need to build and debug with VS.  The full SDK is a separate download.

Comment: You do not need to download a separate installer, just modify the SDK under Programs and Features to enable the 'Debugging Tools for Windows'.  See this [posting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38685339/731081) for more info.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't.

When the Visual Studio installer (2017, 2015, or any other one) gives you the checkbox for "Windows SDK 10.xxxxx" it really means "only the headers (.h), libraries (.lib), metadata (.winmd), etc. from the Windows SDK 10.xxxxx".

It does not include any of the options you see in the Windows SDK installer other than "Windows Software Development Kit". Neither WinDbg and the Debugging Tools for Windows, nor xperf and the Windows Performance Toolkit, nor Application Verifier, nor any of the other things you see int the SDK installer are included  by selecting that checkbox in the VS installer.

The term "Windows SDK" is overloaded with two meanings which are related but not the same. `sdksetup.exe` can install Windows SDK<sub>1</sub>, while the VS installer installs Windows SDK<sub>2</sub> (which is a subset of Windows SDK<sub>1</sub>).

[image]
(Ignore the arrow. Image source: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/analyze-windows-7-performance-with-microsoft-windows-performance-toolkit/)

Comment: I ended up here via Google search. See @sonyisda1's comment on the question for an easier option.

Comment: @Phlucious, that's a separate step. The question was about installing WinDbg/cdb "_during_ Visual Studio install". Obviously if you run the Windows SDK installer you can install WinDbg.

Answer (score 39):

As you noticed, Visual Studio does not allow you to set any options when installing the SDK. However, after the SDK is installed, all you need to do is finding it in "Apps & features" and selecting "Modify". That will present you the options dialog where you can check "Debugging Tools for Windows¨. For me (SDK 10.0.17134.12) it creates the file

`c:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\cdb.exe`

that I set as debugger in Qt Creator. I use it to debug 32bit applications built with msvc2008 express.

Comment: _Apps & features_ is a feature of Windows 10, on Windows 8.1 you should go to _Control Panel > Uninstall or change a program_, select the last _Windows Software Development Kit - Windows <VERSION>_ on the list and click in _Change_ on the top, so the dialog will give the option to select the Debug Tools to install, as said above.

Comment: From what am I concerned this answer should be marked as a solution, as it provides a resolution to the question.

Comment: For me the modify button did just open a dialog which closes immediately. For me worked to download https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=838916 and install debugging tools there. Here is the archive https://developer.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/downloads/sdk-archive

Comment: The directory `Debuggers` doesn't seem to exist any longer or the installation of the Windows Kit 10 doesn't work...

Comment: @fassl I had the same problem because I clicked modify on "Windows SDK AddOn". It worked when I used "Windows Software Development Kit - ..."

Answer (score 16):

Conio already answered, but I'll add a more detailed description for Windows 10. Go to "Apps & Features", search for "Windows Software Development Kit", click on "change" (in the picture "Ändern"), click "change" again, then select "Debugging Tools for Windows".
[image]
[image]
[image]