# Where is the C++ debugger executable located in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-debugging

I am looking for the directory and file name of Visual Studio 2015 debugger to import it into QT Creator.

My problem is, that I have no idea what its name and folder is.
When googling for it only tutorials of how to debug appear.

Comment: It should be something like: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`

Comment: @vahancho thanks, do you also know the name?

Comment: The compiler is `cl.exe`.

Comment: @vahancho but I am looking for the debugger not the compiler ;)

Comment: Just googled it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/debugexe-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After reading all links posted by phonetagger and vahancho I knew what I need looking for...
so: the executables name is **cdb.exe** and it can be found at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64**

BUT! only if **Debugging Tools for Windows** are installed
here is a great discussion about it, and how to install it:

[How to install Debugging Tools with Visual Studio 2017 installer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46237620/how-to-install-debugging-tools-with-visual-studio-2017-installer)

Comment: and how visual studio related to *Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64* ? and why not say windbg.exe in this case ? question and answer unclear

Comment: @RbMm: don't be so literal. The FACT is that Thomas needs cdb (for Qt creator), and a good link describing how to get it happens to have "Visual Studio" in the title.  Thomas - great reply.  Thank you for sharing; please "Accept" when you are able.  Kudos, too, to phonetagger and vahancho.